# how do I solve "The selection cannot be launched" in eclipse STS

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot and I want to launch my first application using eclipse STS

but I am getting error

The selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches.

Most answers I see on the web suggest creating main on one of my file

which I have done but the problem still persist

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.oshabz</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My file structure and main file

[image]

Comment: It seems you haven't run maven update in your project. Do so (Alt + F5) and try again. It might also be that [you need another dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.6.3).

Comment: I have updated the dependencies but nothing is working

Comment: You have two folders. One with the actual project (The one with the `[boot]` tag next to it) and a regular folder. Did you updated the POM in the actual project? Also, please update your screenshot and POM with the added dependencies.

Comment: @JettoMartínez Thank you. I was running the wrong folder. It is working fine now